# how do i change the price feed token from eth /usd to busd/usd with the chainlink oracle?

Tags: oracle, solidity, chainlink

I am trying to get the price feed for BUSD/USD using the chainlink pricefeed oracle but it tells me that the code was reverted. this is also happening when i switch to any other token, i am using the kovan test net

this is the error i get

> call to PriceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice
> call to PriceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice errored: VM execution error.
> Reverted 0x

and this is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xcBb98864Ef56E9042e7d2efef76141f15731B82f);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set incorrect ChainLink address!

correct ETH/USD address: `0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331`

Address you are using in on BSC network, not Kovan network!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get BUSD/USD via a price feed on Kovan testnet, [it is not available on that specific network](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/#Kovan%20Testnet). It is [available on Ethereum mainnet](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/#Ethereum%20Mainnet) however.

If you are testing using the price feed, you can always use a mock contract to mock the behavior of the feeds for testing purposes only.